# Mobile device ID connecting to user to log in to system

Tags: android, iphone, udid

I am currently building a system for mobile phones, the system requires some sort of a login sequence and at the moment I am just using an MD5 generated API which is connected to the user in the database but this is using sessions and so on and has so far proven to not be as good as I had hoped, so now I am trying to build a new login where the user enters the API once and the system detects some sort of ID from the phone, like the SID or MIN or something like that, I have no idea this is possible or not. So to recap

1. Is what I have described possible?
2. What is the most reliable ID that I could fetch from the mobile device?
3. How would I go about fetching this ID?

Comment: users switch phones. How about using a username?

Comment: Well thats the thing haveing to type in a username avery time you need to get in is to much of a hastle, thats why i want the authentication done automatically

Comment: use a username and store it then?

Comment: yeah but then were back where we started, with the sessions and all that